# Getting `Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Received message larger than max (15217288 vs. 4194304)` in Node.js gRPC client

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node, protobufjs

How to increase max message size for Node.js gRPC client?

We use `grpc`, `grpc-tools` and `protobufjs` npm-packages:

```
  const packageDefinitions = loader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, { includeDirs: [__dirname], longs: String, arrays: true });
  const packageObject = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinitions);
  const client = new packageObject.Service(serviceAddress, grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For gRPC client and server we could specify gRPC params. For example, set the max messages size to 100 Mb:

**Client**

```
  const client = new packageObject.Service(serviceAddress, grpc.credentials.createInsecure(), {
    "grpc.max_receive_message_length": 1024 * 1024 * 100,
    "grpc.max_send_message_length": 1024 * 1024 * 100
  });
```

**Server**

```
  const server = new grpc.Server({
    "grpc.max_receive_message_length": 1024 * 1024 * 100,
    "grpc.max_send_message_length": 1024 * 1024 * 100
  });
```